# how do i clone this spring/angularjs git project?

Tags: git

How do I clone [this spring boot / angularJS github project from github](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/modular) into a local CentOS 7 devbox?

Here is the terminal log of what I have tried so far without success:

```
[root@localhost workspace]# git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/modular
Cloning into 'modular'...
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/modular/' not found
[root@localhost workspace]# git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/modular.git
Cloning into 'modular'...
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/modular.git/' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

> git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js.git

If you go to the project's main page (https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js), you can find the clone URL (next to the "HTTPS" drop down).

Comment: Thank you for trying.  But the link you gave is for every possible variation of the code, which is distributed into many different projects.  I am asking how to download and isolate JUST THE PROJECT VERSION FROM SECTION SEVEN OF THE TUTORIAL.  If I use your code, how do I find the project within the download that is just for section seven?  I would then copy that directory and its contents into the root of the eclipse workspace and try to import it into eclipse.

Comment: You should clone the entire repo, and then the part you want will be within the `modular` subdirectory.

Comment: I imagine that i just `cp -r` the `modular` directory into the root of an eclipse workspace and then try to import it into eclipse and also `mvn spring-boot: run` from that directory, but I will need to wait until to tommorow to test that.  If that is the solution, I will write it as a comment and then delete these two comments.